# Storing compressed json data in local storage

Tags: javascript, json, html, compression, local-storage

I want to store JSON data in local storage. Sometimes data stored could be more than 5MB(max threshold allowed by browsers for each domain). Is there anyway i can compress or zip the data and store it in local storage ? How much latency it will add if compression and decompression for every JS function on large data ?

I am using this json data to display on webpage..... It is like a static data which is mostly same for entire session. we provide actions like search, filter etc on this json data...Whenever user enters a keyword, i search in this json data which is stored in local storage instead of making call to server

Comment: What do you need this JSON data stored for?

Comment: I am using this json data to display on webpage..... It is like a static data which is same for entire session. we provide actions like search, filter etc on this json data...Whenever user enters a keyword, i search in this json data which is stored in localstorage instead of making call to server

Comment: I highly doubt it. Local storage was not designed to hold large amounts of data. Why not store this data on the server's cache?

Comment: It seems rather exhaustive to unload everything you've got onto an unsuspecting user... 5MB? No amount of optimisation will compensate for those bandwidth implications - transfer just what you need when you need it in small chunks via ajax.

Comment: @Emissary - It is very less possibility of crossing size more than 5MB. Most of the times, i am serving the same response. For this scenario, why to send another request to server when i can serve from local storage? First time i want to get the data through ajax calls only.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As localStorage functionality seems to be limited to handle only string key/value pairs what you can do is to use [lz-string library](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) to stringify the json object and compress it  before storing it in localStorage

Usage

```
// sample json object
var jsonobj = {'sample': 'This is supposed to be ling string', 'score': 'another long string which is going to be compressed'}

// compress string before storing in localStorage    
localStorage.setItem('mystring', LZString.compress(JSON.stringify(jsonobj)));

// decompress localStorage item stored
var string = LZString.decompress(localStorage.getItem('mystring'))

// parse it to JSON object
JSON.parse(string);
```

Check jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/7PQtC/1/ as i have copied the complete script so look for running code at end of fiddle

Use `compressToUTF16` and `decompressFromUTF16` if you are dealing with UTF characters but please note that the strings produced are therefore 6.66% bigger than those produced by `compress`. So use `utf` ones only when required.

Comment: Do u suggest any ecryption algorithm for morphing before storing in local storage?

Comment: There is one http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#CryptoJS_3.1 but have not used any so cant suggest

Comment: It says on the lz-string website that `compress` produces invalid UTF16 strings and will only work on webkit browsers. `compressToUTF16` and `compressFromUTF16` should be used for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks @vanneto, updated the answer to reflect your comment.