# Best format of localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage

I have array of object tree

```
var tree = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "one",
    "child": [],
    }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "two",
    "child": [{
        "id": "21",
        "name": "twentyOne",
        "child": [],
        },{
        "id": "22",
        "name": "twentyTwo",
        "child": [],
        }],
    }, {{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "three",
    "child": [],
    },
}].
```

Which one is the best way to store array of objects in `localStorage`?
Is it better to use another format?

There are several methods:

- getItem
- getAllItem
- removeItem
- saveItem

But there are child arrays of objects. It means that I will use recursive search to find necessary object.

Comment: consider saving it as a string using `JSON.stringify`..

Comment: It's really up to you. either way you'll have to write the same amount of code doing the same things. What you should keep in mind though is that localStorage storage space is not unlimited.

Comment: To Reddy - I also use JSON.Stringify, thanks.

Comment: To Sergey, yes, I know, that it about 5 mb, and I asked better way)) Couse of size of localStorage, may be better to use another structure of format?

Comment: You may want to consider compression for JSON like [jsonpack](https://github.com/sapienlab/jsonpack) or [LZString](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20774589/1367611).

Comment: try atob and btoa while retrieving

Answer (score 0):

Save the data in LocalStorage as an array, or array of simple objects, but try to keep it **DRY** (don't repeat yourself). For example, if you have a list of people, keep an array of the people, but don't keep a separate variable for the count.

What you want is basically a "state". As long as you keep it minimal you will be fine. Then you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to find, merge, add, remove elements from that array.